# Remember the position in a Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Here's a simple example explaining the problem I'm having:

```
public static String nextTwoTokens(Scanner scan) {
    String partOne = scan.next();
    String partTwo = scan.next();
    return partOne+partTwo;
}
```

This should work just fine, except I don't want to modify the position of the "cursor" in the Scanner with my two `.next()`'s.

From what I've read, you cannot copy a Scanner object. In that case, how would I "remember" the position of the cursor in the Scanner, and then go back to that location before I return in this method?

If I can't do that, is there a way I can get the source the Scanner is reading from in order to build another Scanner? In this case, if I need to create another Scanner, it is fine that the new Scanner starts at the beginning of the file/inputstream/whatever, as opposed to where the old Scanner's cursor was.

Comment: AFAIK, you don't. You can't. And no. You'll need another approach.

Comment: Not entirely sure on this, so I'll leave it as a comment. There is a `Scanner(ReadableByteChannel)` constructor available. There is also a [`FileChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html), which allows you to set the current read position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scanner class doesn't actually implement the Cloneable interface. You could make a custom `.clone()` method by implementing the Cloneable interface, but in this case, cloning is not a good idea.

To answer your question, no, you cannot do this. You'd need to find a better way.

Another way to do this could be to create a `String[]` with the handy `.split(delimiter)` method! So, you could do something like this:

```
String s = "This is a test.";
String[] tokens = s.split(" "); //split the string into tokens, cutting at the spaces
for(String token : tokens) {
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

This should print out

> This 
>   is 
>   a 
>   test.

And that way you can just cycle through the `String[]` to get the next tokens, and return back to your previous spot.

And to answer the question you brought up in the comments, if you want to do something other than a String which doesn't really have a split method, I would recommend just doing this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(INITIALIZE ME HOWEVER YOU WANT);
ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
while(scan.hasNext()) {
    tokens.add(scan.next());
}
```

Basically, just read everything and create a permanent, navigable set of tokens from it.

That's the best advice I can give. It probably isn't the most efficient way, but it's certainly a surefire way to do it.

Comment: How would I use an approach similar to your example, but where the method can accept any type of input that a Scanner would normally be able to parse (as opposed to just Strings)? I looked into the `Readable` interface, but that doesn't include `File`. If I wanted to do this, would I need to make multiple methods, as that of the multiple `Scanner` constructors, and then tokenize them using the equivalent of the `.split` method for whatever Object I'm parsing?

Comment: `Scanner#next()` does not return something else, than `String`, so there is no reason to use `Object` as the generic type for your list.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of the last returned token in the stream by using `scan.match().end()`.

(This does not solve OP's problem, but it is a valid answer to the question's title, and it solves my problem.)